# Azure SQL Database Development Environment

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

How can I setup SQL Azure Database for development. I currently have few SQL databases ProjectName-Development, ProjectName-Staging, ProjectName-Production ...

Is this the right way? This is getting more and more expensive.

Comment: You can check if it compensates that you get an Elastic Pool

Comment: Elastic pool sound like a good idea to reduce cost thanks Carlos

Comment: Depending on the tier required and performance needs yes, but elastic pools start at $75/month, where Azure SQL DB's start at $5/month...see updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend (from experience) using Azure only for Staging and Production environments.  SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition is free (so is SSMS) so you can do all of your local development ... locally.  When you're ready to go to staging, you can then perform a schema compare via your database project (assuming you have one...if not, you should probably create one) and push the schema up to the Azure DB.

The main caveat to this is to be aware of the features that are available in on-premise SQL Server that are NOT available in Azure SQL (e.g. columnstore indexes are only available on the Premium Tier of Azure SQL, no SQL Agent in Azure SQL, tec.).

**Links:**

*SQL Server Download:*
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

*Feature Parity:*
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureedu/2016/07/15/what-features-are-not-supported-in-azure-sql-database/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information

**Edit:** As another user commented, you could put your Dev and Staging DBs in an Elastic Pool, but the cheapest Elastic Pool is ~$75/month currently.  If you MUST have your DEV database in Azure, your cheapest option is to just make it a Basic tier for $5/month.  Not sure what your budget is, but also putting the DBs in a VM is not technically Azure SQL then - it is On-Prem SQL Server on an Azure VM, which will then have feature parity with your local install (of course provided your local install is the same version of SQL Server).

Comment: well i have dev, prod and stagin environments in web services i would like to have databases for each but it is expensive with a lot of projects. I was thinking of setting up a VM for development so all development databases would be on that machine. Locally it is no a problem i have test DB for each project

Comment: more up to date feature parity: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison